# can't call a function declared inside a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, redux

I got an error when trying to call a function declared inside a component. here is the error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined

```
class LanguageDropDown extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {languageValue: ""};
    this.handleLanguageClick = this.handleLanguageClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleLanguageClick = (languageKey) => {
    this.setState({ languageValue: languageKey});
  }

  render() {
    const {intl, value, onChange, onFocus, onBlur, onClick} = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {
          map(languageWhitelist, function(Key) {
            return (
              <option onClick={this.handleLanguageClick(Key)}
              key={Key} value={Key}></option>
             );
            }, this)
          }
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: `handleClick`, as mentioned in the error message, doesn't appear within the snippet provided. Perhaps check other components, especially those that use the `LanguageDropDown` as content.

Comment: maybe try this `<option onClick={() => this.handleLanguageClick(Key)} key={Key} value={Key}></option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```js
class LanguageDropDown extends Component {
  state = { languageValue: '' };

  _handleLanguageClick(languageValue) {
    this.setState({ languageValue });
  };

  render() {
    const { intl, value, onChange, onFocus, onBlur, onClick } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {languageWhitelist.map(language => (
          <option
            onClick={() => this._handleLanguageClick(language)}
            key={language}
          >
            {language}
          </option>
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was helpful, the error no longer appears however handleLanguageClick does not run

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by does not run? its not getting called at all or the component is not rendering ?

Comment: component is rendering fine, but events its not getting called , _handleLanguageClick(languageValue) {
    this.setState({ languageValue });
console.log("test");
  };
I put some logs to check but i get nothing into console

Comment: I edited the code a bit and verified in codesandbox. Everything works fine for me,

Answer (score 0):

By using arrow functions inside a class,it becomes automatically bound to the class,
so just remove the binding statement from the constructor.
And also set the **onClick** props to a callback function.

```
class LanguageDropDown extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { languageValue: '' };
  }

  _handleLanguageClick = languageValue => {
    this.setState({ languageValue });
  };

  render() {
    const { intl, value, onChange, onFocus, onBlur, onClick } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {languageWhitelist.map(language => (
          <option
            onClick={() => this._handleLanguageClick(language)}
            key={language}
          >
            {language}
          </option>
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```